# Recursive query on Oracle based on Alias field

Tags: oracle

I need to write a query that returns the parent - child fields based on the field alias where alias is not null, my table has three fields parent,child and alias mapped to the child field. Something like:

```
select nvl(alias, parent) as al_parent,
       nvl(alias, child) as al_child 
from BI.TEMP_PARENT_CHILD
where parent in (select child from BI.TEMP_PARENT_CHILD)
```

Table:

```
PARENT      CHILD       SORTID      ALIAS
p1          c1          1           CIA
p1          c2          2           C2A
c2          c22         3           (null)
```

Comment: take a look at the CONNECT BY syntax in Oracle. That may help to solve your problem.

Comment: not the case I guess

Comment: Please [post formatted text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), and include the output you are trying to get from that data, and why your current query results are not what you need.

Comment: my output should be a query with two fields , alias-parent and alias-child